# Mount for AWS CLI config not working as expected in devcontainer.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I am experimenting with dev containers in Visual Studio Code. My goal is to get the AWS CLI to work correctly with SSO authentication.

Used source: https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-local-file-mount

My current device is based on the Windows OS (however a final implementation should not be OS specific).

At the location: `C:\Users\UserName\.aws\config` I have my configuration file stored, that holds the information required for an SSO login (the given values are fictional):

```
[profile dev]
sso_start_url = https://sso-url.com
sso_region = eu-central-1
sso_account_id = 111222333444
sso_role_name = my-named-role
region = eu-central-1
output = json
```

My `.devcontainer.json` looks as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Python 3",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:1-3.11-bookworm",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/aws-cli:1": {
            "version": "latest"
        }
    },
    "postCreateCommand": "pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt",
    "mounts": [
        "source=${localEnv:HOME}${localEnv:USERPROFILE}/.aws,target=/root/.aws,type=bind"
    ]
}
```

After spinning up the container I van see the file is present:
[image]

However when I try to login using the dev profile I get:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the CLI expects the `config` to be stored at `~`, which is the home directory. Printing `echo $HOME` I found that shoud not be `/root/` but `/home/vscode/`.